# Complex Startup Logic in iOS Apps: Where Should it Reside?

Tags: ios

Everyone has seen the classic didFinishLaunchingMethod run amok.

Well now that we have additional things to consult when starting up like CloudKit, that are, to make things worse, asynchronous, the app delegate seems like the wrong place to do even the most basic stuff like asking if they have accounts and establishing syncing, or grabbing a snapshot.

I hate the idea that those things would go into the first controller that the app would launch, flashes me back to 4GL tinkertoys from days of yore.

Yet, we have to honor the flows of the storyboards. I have found nothing searching around on this. And sadly the most extensive Apple example, Lister, is not a great source for best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's suitable for the app delegate to trigger the start of this work, but not to handle the results. Often you want some way to display progress / errors / request user info. So, having some form of 'splash' view controller which handles the transition from your launch image into this process and controls the flow into the main app is handy. Generally the logic for this kind of thing is reusable in other situations so that part should be in some other controller class. The storyboard can make the splash VC the initial controller and the app delegate can create and pass it the data controller class which deals with the logic and updates the VC (it's delegate) with the results. Often the splash VC will then pass the data controller on to the subsequent VC it displays, though that isn't required of course.